# Continuous function with non-negative second derivative in the weak sense is convex

Tags: real-analysis, riemannian-geometry

I am currently working through a section of Peter Petersen's Riemannian Geometry in which he talks about weak second derivatives of functions. I am trying to work through the details of why a function on a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ with non-negative Hessian in the weak sense is convex.

I understand how one can reduce the problem to the case where $M$ is the real line with the Euclidean metric by precomposing with unit speed geodesics, so I have been able to reduce the problem to the following:

> **Proposition:** Let $f$ be a continuous function defined on an open interval in $\mathbf{R}$. We say that $f''(p)\geq 0$ in the weak sense if for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a smooth function $f_\varepsilon$ defined in a neighborhood of $p$ such that
>
> (1) $f(p)=f_\varepsilon(p)$
>
> (2) $f\geq f_\varepsilon$
>
> (3) $f_\varepsilon''(p)\geq -\varepsilon$.
>
> Then if $f''\geq 0$ everywhere in the weak sense, then $f$ is convex.

I have tried for a while to come up with a direction to move in from here. My ideas keep running into the problem that the definition of $f_\varepsilon$ only necessarily has nice properties in a small neighborhood of $p$.

This makes the naive approach of trying to directly apply the definition of convexity more difficult (compared to when we assume our function is actually twice differentiable). Given $x_1$, $x_2$ and $t\in(0,1)$, for example, we cannot guarantee the function $f_\varepsilon$ defined around $p=tx_1+(1-t)x_2$ is even defined at $x_1$ or $x_2$.

I have a feeling I am over-thinking this problem. I would appreciate any input/hints anyone would be willing to provide as to how I might proceed from here.

Comment: Welcome to mathSE.  It would be good if you highlighted exactly what your question is (many people won't want to read through your huge wall of text just to find what it is you are asking about).  For instance, if your question is about proving the proposition in the middle of your post, you could quote that block of text by putting `>` at the start of each line.

Comment: Thanks, edited to highlight what my question is.

Answer (score 2):

I got stuck exactly at the same point. Here is a quite simple argument to prove your Proposition.

First of all, you can reduce to prove this:

> **Lemma:** Let $f$ be a continuous function defined on an open interval in $\mathbf{R}$. Suppose for every $p$ there exists a convex function $g_p$ defined in a neighborhood of $p$ such that
>
> (1) $f(p)=g_p(p)$
>
> (2) $f\geq g_p$.
>
> Then $f$ is convex.

To deduce the Proposition from the Lemma, fix any $\epsilon>0$ and set $h_\epsilon(x):=\epsilon x^2$.
For every $p$ choose a function $f_\epsilon$ (defined on $U_p$) as in the hypothesis and observe that $f+h_\epsilon\ge f_\epsilon+h_\epsilon$ (on $U_p$), with equality at $p$. 
Moreover $(f_\epsilon+h_\epsilon)''(p)\ge -\epsilon+2\epsilon>0$, so wlog $g_p:=f_\epsilon+h_\epsilon$ is convex on $U_p$. 
Now the Lemma implies that $f+h_\epsilon$ is convex. As $f+h_\epsilon\to f$ (uniformly on compact sets) as $\epsilon\to 0$, we conclude that $f$ is convex too.

**Proof of the Lemma:** observe that $f$ is convex iff, for any linear function $\phi$, the sublevel sets $\{f-\phi\le \alpha\}$ are convex for any $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ (tell me if this is not clear). 
So pick any linear function $\phi$ and put $F:=f-\phi$. Let $x_1,x_2\in\{F\le\alpha\}$; we have to prove that $[x_1,x_2]\subseteq\{F\le\alpha\}$. 
Assume by contradiction that $M:=\max_{[x_1,x_2]}F>\alpha$ and call $p\in(x_1,x_2)$ the first point (of the interval) at which $f$ equals $M$ (i.e. $p:=\min f^{-1}(M)\cap [x_1,x_2]$). Now $F$ still satisfies the hypotheses (of the Lemma), so we can find a convex $G:U\to\mathbb{R}$ ($U\subseteq (x_1,x_2)$ being a neighborhood of $p$) such that $F\ge G$ with equality at $p$. 
So $G$ reaches its maximum at $p$ (since $G\le F\le F(p)=G(p)$ on $U$); but convexity easily implies that $G\equiv M$ on all of $U$: for example we know that the slope $s(x):=\frac{G(x)-G(p)}{x-p}$ is an increasing function on $U\setminus\{p\}$, but $s(x)\ge 0$ if $x<p$ and $s(x)\le 0$ if $x>p$ since $G(p)$ is the maximum value. If you draw a picture everything becomes clear.
Thus $r\equiv 0$, so $G\equiv M$. Finally, since $F\ge G$, we get $F\equiv M$ on $U$; but this contradicts the fact that $F<M$ on $[x_1,p)$. $\blacksquare$

Answer (score -1):

Here's an outline of what I believe to be a proof. Simpler ones may exist, but this is what I came up with. I haven't really been pedantic at all about details (as you'll see) but maybe this will give you some ideas.

**Lemma.** If $f'' \geq 0$ everywhere in the weak sense, then for every smooth, compactly supported function $\varphi$ on $\mathbb{R}$ with $\varphi \geq 0$,
$$
\int f \varphi'' \geq 0.
$$

**Proof sketch.** For any $\epsilon$, show that one can cover the support of $\varphi$ with finitely many disjoint half-open intervals $J_1, \dots, J_k$ such that there exists for each $1 \leq i \leq k$ a smooth function $f_i$ defined on $J_i$ and satisfying $f \geq f_i$ and $f_i'' > -\epsilon$ on $J_i$. Estimate the integral above by breaking it up into integrals over the $J_i$ and using integration by parts and the functions $f_i$.

**Proposition.** If $f'' \geq 0$ everywhere in the weak sense, then $f$ is convex.

**Proof sketch.** By adding a linear function to $f$, it suffices to show that for $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $f(a) = f(b) = 0$, we have $f(t) \leq 0$ for $a < t < b$.

Suppose otherwise. Then there is $c$ with $a < c < b$ such that $f(c) = C > 0$. By the intermediate value theorem there exists $c_1, c_2$ with $a < c_1 < c < c_2 < b$ such that $f(c_1) = f(c_2) = C/4$. By continuity, the values of $f$ are close (say, within $\epsilon$) to $c$ or $c/4$ respectively within an $\eta$-neighborhood of the points $c$ and $c_1, c_2$ respectively.

One now constructs an appropriate smooth function $\psi$ supported on the $\eta$-neighborhoods of these three points, positive near $c_1$ and $c_2$ and negative near $c$, and sufficiently well-controlled so that (1) There exists a second antiderivative $\varphi$ of $\psi$ which is smooth and of compact support, and (2) The integral $\int f \varphi''$ can be estimated (and proved to be negative). Together with the lemma, this proves the proposition.

Comment: The proof sketch of the Lemma seems nonsense as we don't have control on the sign of $\phi''$

Comment: @Mizar There was a typo; I want $f_i'' > - \epsilon$, of course, as in the given definition of "$f'' > 0$ in the weak sense" given in the original question. The integral should be done by parts twice, putting the derivatives on the $f_i$, so the sign of $\phi''$ doesn't ever matter.